# Customize infowindow google maps error

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to customize the infowindow of google maps, however I can not remove the white box.

Someone can help me?

Code (CSS):

```
.gm-style-iw {
  background:black;
  border:2px solid black;
  opacity: 0.95;
  color:white;
  margin-top: 65px;    
  margin-left: 68px;
  position: fixed;
}

/*Code to remove arrow and close button*/

.gm-style div div div div div div div div div {
  display: none;
}

.gm-style-iw + div {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Google changed something, because I already had my map working fine and now it has this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the rules under `/*Code to remove arrow and close button*/` with these:

```
.gm-style div div div div div div div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.gm-style-iw + div {
  display: none;
}
.gm-style div div div div div div.gm-style-iw div div {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The first rule hides the white box but also hides the text in the black info window so the third rule makes the text visible again.

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/purowov/3/edit?css,output) to see a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code solved the problem perfectly :)

Comment: Have you seen or used the [snazzy-info-window library](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window) before? It may make customizing your info windows easier.